# Showing a different navigation controller if it's the first time using the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

The app is going to have a specific 'journey' for new users to follow when they first use the application. This is a separate `NavigationController` from the `TabController` which encompases the core app.

I know I can store whether or not someone has been through the process before. My question is where would be the correct place to handle this logic. Would you do it in the `AppDelegate` within *`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`*. Or within the `TabViewController`. Or somewhere completely different?

I'm not too sure how I'd handle it within the `delegate`, it just feels like a cleaner way to do it.

Within the `TabViewController`, I'd perform a segue to the `NavigationController`. I don't want there to be any visible transition to the `NavigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you implement a first-launch-only screen, or sequence of screens, by presenting one or more modal view controllers if the code logic decides they are needed. Then when you dismiss them, the normal app UI is waiting underneath.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds logical. Where would you usually launch the modal view? Is that something you'd handle before it gets to the root controller (AppDelegate) or something that gets dealt with when the root controller loads.

Comment: I'm displaying it as a modal view when the TabBarController loads (viewDidAppear). Thanks.